# catching signals with qt promoted class

Tags: c++, qt

Started learning the basics of Qt a few days ago and my question involves the following:
- Qt designer (UI)
- promoted classes

With Qt designer (or even without it I believe), to "catch signals" or create an event, we can do something like create a private slot like this: "on_[widget_name]_[signal_name]." The following code works and I have no problems here:

```
#include "custom.h"
#include "ui_custom.h"
#include <QDebug>

CustomWidget::CustomWidget(QWidget *parent) :
  QWidget(parent),
  ui(new Ui::CustomWidget)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
//  ui->horizontalLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
//  ui->horizontalLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
}

CustomWidget::~CustomWidget()
{
  delete ui;
}

void CustomWidget::on_widthInput_valueChanged(int value){
  qDebug() << "test";
}
```

My question is **Is there a way to define the same on_[widget]_[signal] event in a promoted class?**

In other words, pretend there is a GCWidget::GCWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) but it is only a promoted class from Qt Designer. It has the same void function on_widthInput_valueChanged but unfortunately, "test" will not be outputted.

The reason I want to do this is obviously, I don't want to have all my code polluted in one parent class for my UI. I read that the idea of the promoted class is to give me the possibility of separating these classes but when I created that same "on_..." function, it did not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want re implement  `on_widthInput_valueChanged` in derived class, just declare it as `virtual` in base class, or if you want achive some else, please describe in more details

Comment: Sorry, I added one more paragraph to explain. The promoted classes have are "children" in the Qt Designer but they are not "children" in the C++ class tree so I'm not talking about inheriting the object.

Comment: I suppose you should read about `Qt signals/slots` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html), they not connected by defining functions with special names, they connected by calling `connect` function, in your case `connect` is situated in auto-generated code, that's why not see it. So you need just call `connect` manually, or reuse already existing connection by using `virtual`